# Showing algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue is at least two

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently working on the following question:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator that has two linearly independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. Prove that $\lambda$ is a multiple root of the characteristic polynomial of $T$. In other words, show that $(t-\lambda)^2$ divides the characteristic polynomial.

I find problems like this incredibly frustrating, because I see it's clearly true - but proving it is another matter.

Say that $T : V \rightarrow V$, then there is a basis $\bf{B}$ 
 of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis is upper triangular and since $\lambda$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$ we can find a $\bf{B}$ such that $v_1, v_2 \in \bf{B}$ and so this gives:

$\chi_A(t) = \det(tI - A) = (t-a_{11})(t-a_{22})...(t-a_{nn})$

Since $v_1, v_2$ are column vectors of the matrix $A$, we have that two of $a_{ii} = \lambda$ so

$\det(tI - A) = (t-a_{11})(t-a_{22})...(t-\lambda)(t-\lambda)...(t-a_{nn})$

$\det(tI - A) = (t-a_{11})(t-a_{22})...(t-\lambda)^2...(t-a_{nn})$

and so $(t-\lambda)^2$ divides the characteristic polynomial. This is my attempt at it, but I'm not convinced it even works. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your proof. First, it is not necessarily true that you can find a basis $B$ such that the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $B$ is upper triangular. You can always find one over $\mathbb{C}$, but not over $\mathbb{R}$, not to mention other fields. Second, even if such bases exist, why can you find one that contains $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Actually, you may prove the statement in a legitimate but slightly different way. Extend $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to a basis $B$ of $V$. Then the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $B$ is *block* upper triangular, where the upper left block is $\lambda I_2$. Note that for a block matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&C\end{pmatrix}$ where $A,C$ are square matrices, $\det M=(\det A)(\det C)$. Now the rest is straightforward.